# Evaluate the complex integral $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{e^z}{z(z^2-1)(z+1)}dz$.

Tags: complex-integration

How I can  solve this complex integral?

> $$\int_{|z|=2}\dfrac{e^z}{z(z^2-1)(z+1)}dz$$

I know how to find the singularities but I do not understand in this case how to distribute the fractions of the integral. I mean $A/(x-a)$ etc....
The singularities are:  $z=0$,$z=\pm 1$, $z=-1$. I got stuck.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Use integral Cauchy theorem or Residue theorem.

Answer (score 1):

With Residue theorem we see all denominator zeros $z=0,1,-1$ lie in circle $|z|=2$, for $f(z)=\dfrac{e^z}{z(z^2-1)(z+1)}$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}_{z=0}f(z)=\lim_{z\to0}(z-0)f(z)=-1,\\
\operatorname{Res}_{z=1}f(z)=\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)f(z)=\dfrac{e}{4},\\
\operatorname{Res}_{z=-1}f(z)=\lim_{z\to-1}[(z+1)^2f(z)]'=\dfrac{5}{4e},\\
\end{align}
then
$$\int_{|z|=2}\dfrac{e^z}{z(z^2-1)(z+1)}=2\pi i\sum_{0,1,-1} \operatorname{Res}=2\pi i\left(-1+\dfrac{e}{4}+\dfrac{5}{4e}\right)$$

Comment: OP says "I do not understand in this case how to distribute the fractions of the integral". Does OP know Residue theorem?

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, I forgot to try with the residue method-theorem. Thanks for your help!